# How to trigger GateKeeper quarantine without uploading/ downloading the file/ installer?

Tags: macos, osx-gatekeeper

I made a `pkg` installer and I'm trying to debug the codesigning issue where GateKeeper has put the quarantine flag on the installer.

This quarantine translates to the `permission denied` when the application through the **CLI**, or when double clicking, or when right clicking > open:

[image]

It does this **only** when the installer gets downloaded. I think I have figured out why the installer gets quarantined by GateKeeper, but the only way I can test this is by uploading it and then downloading it. This is slow, and I would like to run GateKeeper checks without wasting time uploading to the internet.

I read somewhere that zip`ing the file and unzipping it might work, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I came up with is to **drag and drop the file onto a web browser and re-download it** from the browser. This doesn't use any internet. It still passes through GateKeeper since the quarantine flag is re-added to the `.pkg` file.

Even Apple doesn't suggest this:

> Quarantine a copy of your app. You can do this in either of the following ways:
>
> - Email the app to yourself and use the copy that Mail downloads.
> - Host the app on your own local or remote server and use the copy that Safari downloads